# Creation of HTTP server

Tags: java

I am learning Java and was given a task to implement a simplistic version of HTTP server that is able to:

- accept `/GET` requests and route them based on the uri
- accept `/POST` requests and route them based on the uri
- respond with a proper HttpResponse

Here is where I am so far:

```
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(7777);
    Socket socket = server.accept();

    String httpResponse = "Http/1.1 200/OK\r\n\r\n " + new Date();
    socket.getOutputStream().write(httpResponse.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

and I am stuck. I understand how to return a "Hello World" HTTP response to everything, but I have no idea how to deal with HTTP requests.

Could you give me a possible direction or a couple of next steps I can take to move forward?

Comment: Can you use Jetty or some other server?

Comment: What do you mean by "route them based on the uri"?  Is this "simplistic" HTTP server supposed to support multiple simplistic Web applications as well?

Comment: If you need to have a HTTP java server then you can simply use jetty like thing. You don't need a ServerSocket  for a simple http server. If you can provide more details on your requirement I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: There is nothing simple about an HTTP server. You need to start by reading RFC 2616 as amended and superceded. Too broad.

Comment: I'm guessing (and it's only a guess) that this is some sort of educational exercise, and the Java is supposed to call some method depending on whether the request was a POST or a GET. If so, you'll need to read the client's input before generating output. Right now, all you do is accept the client's connection and send a response. If you use socket.getInputStream() you should be able to read the client's request, which should being "GET /something HTTP/1.1" or similar, parse it, and make some decision how to handle it.

Comment: yes, this is an educational exercise, and I thought I would need to use `socket.getInputStream()` convert it to String and parse by tokens, but I need to understand whether this is the right approach and if it is what the recommendation would be. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a basic example of an HTTP request you could use a tool like Postman (Google Chrome extension) or HttpRequester (Firefox extension) which allows you to construct requests and view the code.

For example here is a basic request:

```
GET /news/headlines?hl=en HTTP/1.1
Host: news.google.com
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

This request gets the Google News headlines page.

If you're looking for how to use sockets you could start with the [Java Lesson: All About Sockets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html)